# ROS Answers SE migration: c++ api gazebo

Tags: gazebo, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm new in Ros.
I want to see a example of a program in c++ where i can see how i can move the joints.
I'm a beginner, so i can't know how I can find thiys information.
Thank you
Angelo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28768/c++-api-gazebo/) by [manang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1809/manang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the ros libraries and plugins. You add a controller in gazebo which listens to a topic, e.g. gazebo_ros_force. For your case you might want to use gazebo_ros_p3d, to change the position instead of force.

Add a controller to your urdf file like so:

```
<controller:gazebo_ros_force name="controller_name" plugin="libgazebo_ros_force.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
  <topicName>force1</topicName>
  <bodyName>body_name</bodyName>
</controller:gazebo_ros_force>
```

This is a force controller which listen to the topic /force1.

You then use the roscpp api to publish and subscribe to the gazebo topics. You can find a good guide for creating these publisher and subscribers [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

But you change the example for publishing wrenches and listening to gazebo link states. Like i did with a force controller:

```
   ros::NodeHandle nh; 
   pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Wrench>("force1", 5);
   sub = nh.subscribe<gazebo_msgs::LinkStates>("gazebo/link_states", 1000, linkstatesCallback); //ROS gazebo publishes all joint states, you can use these.
```

I publish forces and i listen to positions and create a feedback loop. It is obviously easier to just change position with a different controller if that is what you are after.

Publishing is easy and goes like this:

```
 pub.publish(wrench);
 ros::spinOnce();
```

You can also work around ROS by using the actual gazebo API, however in my opinion the documentation for the older version is limited. I would not recommend this unless you really need direct access to the simulator.

*Combine these snippets with the tutorials it should work*

---

Originally posted by [Erik_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1614/erik_s/) with karma: 103 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3